# I want to enable Hyper-V in Windows Features, but there is no Hyper-V option

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am very very confused about this.
I have a Sony Vaio I7 laptop (There is a Hyper-V setting in bios, so I am easy to enable Hyper-V)

I want to develop Windows Phone 8. I have read [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx) from Microsoft 
but even if I enable Hyper-V in bios, Windows Feature does not show Hyper-V option like MSDN guide.

(At first there is Hyper-V in windows feature but I don't know Hyper-V missing lately)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you friends.

(I attach an image)
[image: My Windows Feature (hyper lost]

[image: Visual Studio 2012 when try to launch windows phone 8 emulator]

Comment: You never explicitly say what version of windows you are using.

Comment: What is the version of the OS? Is this Windows 8 Pro x64? You also need a CPU that supports SLAT.

Comment: You're using Windows 8 basic, which doesn't have the option present?

Comment: i use windows 8.1 single language 64 bit....

Answer (score 8):

You will need the pro version to get the hyper-v feature.
You can read here for more help as well:
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

Comment: i use windows 8.1 single language? but at first there is hyper - v in windows feature but lately hyper-v missing

Comment: Try looking at this article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/837383cf-d513-4360-942c-9cceb9d018f0/hyperv-manager-available-but-role-is-missing-in-server-manager?forum=winserverhyperv

Answer (score 4):

If someone is having this problem of missing tickbox on Windows 7 Pro, it can be solved by installing

[Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887).

Answer (score 3):

Only problem your Hyper-V is not running is because you Don't have the Windows 8 Pro version of the window. So get that first.