# How to Disable Hyper-V and install HAXM in Windows 8

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, hyperthreading, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM for android studio but it is showing error:

[image]

Now my system has VT-x enabled:

[image]

after this I tried to disable HYPER-V but when i try through cmd it shows a error:

[image]

In windows feature I dont have a HYPER-V option:

[image]

I have uninstalled my AVAST anti virus and I have tried to disable HYPER-V through powershell also but it is not working..

I am using windows 8.1 64-bit OS with intel i5

Please Help
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Doing lot of search on internet about this problem I Finally found out a solution which is working for me. It is a Hardware issue and I switched to windows 8 PRO version and then Everything worked just Fine.

Have a look at this question it also says the same:
[I want to enable Hyper-V in Windows Features, but there is no Hyper-V option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052534/i-want-to-enable-hyper-v-in-windows-feature-but-there-is-no-hyper-v-option)

Thanks!!