# When I use android studio, i got error related with HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, intel, haxm

Description:

When I start developing Android Studio, I have a problem to run emulator which said I need to ensure HAXM module installed. But I cannot install HAXM module on my pc, because install file said my CPU isn't adequate with these module to install. I have a cpu model i3-2120, which have a support for VT-x and I enabled this feature in BIOS, but it doesn't affect the fact which I cannot install HAXM on my machine.

Questions:

- If VT-x is all about requirement to install HAXM, why i cannot install HAXM?
- What CPU model is adequate to install HAXM? (I think VT-x doesn't sufficient to install HAXM. there's more requirements..)

Comment: You could use an ARM emulator instead, though it will be very slow.

Comment: Conflict with Hyper-V? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301234/how-to-disable-hyper-v-and-install-haxm-in-windows-8

Answer (score 2):

Intel HAXM requires 4 things:

1. Intel processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), **and** Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality. All these functionality are required on your processor.
2. 1 GB **available** RAM
3. Android SDK version 17 or higher
4. Windows Vista/7/8
   (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

It appears that i3-2120 does have VT-x, Intel 64 and Execute Disable Bit, so technically your processor is supported. (http://ark.intel.com/products/53426/Intel-Core-i3-2120-Processor-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz)

Please check your **available** RAM, by going to Windows Task Manager > Performance > Physical Memory > Available. Is it > 1 GB?

Also, update your Android SDK to the latest version by running SDK Manager.

Let us know how it goes!

If this answer is helpful, please mark it as accepted! Thanks!

Comment: Note FYI -- it also works on a Mac if it's an Intel based one.

Comment: I checked that my RAM capacity is 4GB, and I don't know what is exactly Android SDK version, but from the list of SDK manager, Android SDK Tools Revision is 24.1.2, Platform-tools 22, Build-tools 22.0.1, etc..(I install packages recently, revision of SDK manager is 24.1.2), still I cannot install HXAM..

Comment: Did you check that Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS settings? There's usually a BIOS option for Virtualization that you have to set explicitly to "Enabled".

Comment: Yeap, I did "Virtualization" enabled in BIOS settings, but situation still remaines in same error while I developed in my own real device, that is unconfortable,,