# Hyper-V is not available as a choice in Turning on/off Windows Features

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I don't have Hyper-V available as one of the choices in Windows Features in Windows 8.1 (not the pro version). Any idea how could I have it?

My computer supports virtualization and virtualization is already enabled.
I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052534/i-want-to-enable-hyper-v-in-windows-feature-but-there-is-no-hyper-v-option) before but there's no real solution for Windows8.1.

[image]
[image]

[image]

If there's no viable solution, how can I update/upgrade to Windows8.1 pro from Windows8.1 home edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V is a feature of the Pro/Enterprise Editions of Windows 8/8.1 and not of the Core Edition. You have to buy an upgrade key to go to Pro.