# Facing Android emulator starting issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

When I try to run emulator before running android sample project I'm getting this error. Can anyone let me know what's wrong?

[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EGzS.png)

Comment: You require Hardware acceleration on your machine. Do you have it?

Comment: i really dont know about Hardware acceleration

Comment: Google it. It's graphical rendering by hardware, GPU.

Comment: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)  is already installed, for hardware accelration

Comment: Did you install intel HAXM?

Comment: There is no any package with this text "intel HAXM" in the list of SDK Manager.only this is mentioned "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" Also fyi this emulator was starting fine few days back but nowit is showing error like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by missing Hyper-V, but you'll need a *Pro* version of Windows to do so. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052697/1649102) for more details on the issue.